# Getting a changed variable to show up in `render`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Probably a simple question with a simple answer, but I can't figure this out. Blame the heat. **My simulator prints 'this is a test' on the screen, when I want it to say 'changed'.** What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Template from './src/components/Template';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.foo= "this is a test";
  }

  changeMe = () => {
    this.foo = 'changed';
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.changeMe();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Template foo={this.foo} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: seems you haven't grasped the react way of doing things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use state

You are using a class attribute witch will not trigger a re-render when changed. In react a component will re-render when it receives new props or when the state is changed (there's also a way to force it but best not to do that).

## Example using the state to trigger a rerender

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Template from './src/components/Template';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={foo: "this is a test"};
    }

    changeMe = () => {
        this.setState({foo:'changed'})
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.changeMe();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Template foo={this.state.foo} />
        );
    }
}
```

When passing new props to a component it will also re-render (unless you implement componentShouldUpdate).

## State explanation

So inside a react component you have a local state object in `this.state` it can be set in the constructor like `this.state = {bar: 'foo'};`. After the constructor has set the state it should only be changed with the `this.setState()` method.

Upon changing the state with setState the component will re-render with the updated values.

The state is not available outside of the component, at least not available as `this.state` because that would call the local state of the current component.

If you need to use a value from the state of a parent component you can pass it to a child. At that point it becomes a prop of the child accessible with
`this.props`

To change the value of state from a child component you should pass a function to the child that changes the state of the parent.

This process of passing state changing functions becomes increasingly complex as your app grows, I would suggest using a library like Redux to manage app state via actions and reducers. There is a steep learning curve but once you have a grasp of this modified flux methodology you will wonder how you ever lived without it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've run into a different problem changing state from a different component now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316385/changing-state-from-a-child-component